# How to create middleware that gets the user's IP in golang

Tags: go, web, web-applications, middleware

I want to create middleware that grabs the user's IP when the page is loaded. I know the actual code to do this is:

```
//GetClientIpAddr gets the client IP
func GetClientIpAddr(req *http.Request) string {
    clientIp := req.Header.Get("X-FORWARDED-FOR")
    if clientIp != "" {
        return clientIp
    }
    return req.RemoteAddr
}
```

However this only runs as a function in which I have to run in every handler function for a page.

My problem is that I want to be able to call this in as middleware in my separate routes.go file so that it applies to every page loaded which better functionality. Chi has a similar middleware called Logger. It achieves what I want, however I want to build it myself and know how to call it in as middleware via Chi.Use(functionthatgetsuserIP).

I tried calling the function mentioned above as middleware, but since the function doesn't meet the requirements, I can't call it in as middleware. I can only call it individually in each handler for each page as logic.

======== ======== ======== ======== ======== ======== ======== ======== ======== =======

Answer (score 0):

To put meta-data into a http.Request, one can add use the requests associated `context.Context`. This way it can be added in a middleware and accessed downstream in any route, no matter how many middlewares you may have.

The general gist is this:

```
type ctxKey string                 // private type to avoid any conflicts
const ctxUserIP = ctxKey("userip") // instance of this type 

// Note: you can store a whole struct with many fields here, but for simplicity
//       we'll just define setter/getter for a simple string value
func setIP(ctx context.Context, ip string) context.Context {
        return context.WithValue(ctx, ctxUserIP, ip)
}
func getIP(ctx context.Context) (ip string, ok bool) {
        user, ok = ctx.Value(ctxUserIP).(string)
        return
}
```

The middleware code would look something like:

```
func ipMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {  
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ip := r.Header.Get("X-FORWARDED-FOR") // get IP ...
       
        h.ServeHTTP(w,
            // update request context ... 
            r.WithContext(
                setIP(r.Context(), ip), // ... using current context + IP info added
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

wrap any routes with this middleware:

```
// http.Handle("/myapi", http.HandlerFunc(myapi)) // unwrapped

// wrapped
http.Handle("/myapi",
    ipMiddleware(
        http.HandlerFunc(myapi),
    ),
)
```

and finally in your `myapi` code:

```
func myapi(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    ctx := r.Context() // get downstream context

    ip, ok := getIP(ctx) // get IP from context (embedded by ipMiddleware)

    // ...
}
```